# I don't understand the error on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Please somebody can help me with my error, there is nothing on console, but I can't run the project. This is creenshot:
[image]

thanks for help

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "I can't run the project"? What are you doing, and what's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the Problems tab at the bottom, see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Clean your projects by going

**Eclipse>Project>clean**

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project (menu/Project/Clean). The project tree looks as if there's a compilation error in one of the files - there's a red "x" on the project; typically, the similar "x" would be on the problematic file. Which can be a source, or a resource, or the manifest. Open up the tree and try to find one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the build path, maybe you forgot to add a library or move it.